# Overriding assigned IP address using DHCP on FreeBSD 12

Tags: networking, freebsd, dhcp, ip-address

Is there some way to assign a preferred IP address despite using DHCP? i.e., to use DHCP to find the router and network mask, but assign the IP address manually (ideally with fallback).

`/etc/rc.conf` (relevant lines)

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_em0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
rtsold_enable="YES"
```

Comment: There would be no standard way in the DHCP protocol for your client to tell the server "Thanks, but I'm using this IP address instead." As a result, the DHCP server might assign another client to the IP address you've chosen to use, causing an IP address conflict. The proper way to solve this is usually at the DHCP server, by configuring it to assign a specific preferred IP address to a specific client. The client is usually identified by its MAC address, but if the DHCP server is flexible enough, any attribute present in the client's DHCP request may be used.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for explaining. Looks like the best way to do it would be to add an entry in the router's table, with the computer's MAC address.